# How do I use navigation guards in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

I have reused my component in Vue.js, and tried to use 'beforeRouteEnter' navigation guard to update my data fields inside that component. But the component is not updating. Should I have used another navigation guard?

```
beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {
    this.getServices()
    next()
  },
methods: {
getServices() {
    axios.get('/service').then(res => {
      console.log(res)
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err)  
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: The beforeRouteEnter guard does NOT have access to this, because the guard is called before the navigation is confirmed, thus the new entering component has not even been created yet.
Read the documentation here:
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html

Comment: I tried using beforeRouteUpdate aswell. But it doesnot work.

Answer (score 0):

`beforeRouteEnter` doesn't have access to `this`. You would have to use a function that is defined outside of the object scope and call the function before next. The argument passed to next is the your vue component object so that you can set the properties of the component.

Something like this will work:

```
beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {
  axios.get('/service').then(res => {
    next(vm => {
      vm.res = res
    })
  }).catch(err => {
    next(vm => {
      vm.err = err
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: I tried this code that you provided. It gives me an error saying (Arrow function should not return assignment). And also it says 'vm' is not defined.

Comment: I actually fixed the problem using `beforeRouteUpdate`, where I can have access to `this` keyword.

Comment: Oops, my bad. it should be like this `next(vm => { vm.res = res })`

Comment: Well, it didn't show any error, but the value of response coming from axios is not showing in the console. Why is that?

Comment: If you want to log the response, you have to add `console.log(res)`